# Words that define spectrums of quantity and consensus

Tags: meaning, word-choice, vocabulary

I need to fill a 4x4 grid with words, as seen here:

[image]

I'm not quite sure how to fill in each blank box. They should be a spectrum of controversy to consensus, and minority to majority. This grid of words will help describe things that are agreed upon (or not) by many people.

So something that is very polarizing between many people should be controversial and a majority, if it's something polarizing between few people it should reflect that it is a minority and also controversial.

Comment: English doesn't have many words for in-between states; normally we pick an extreme or the middle and vary from it. And 4 x 4 doesn't have a midpoint, so you miss a lot of possibilities.

Comment: What's the difference between a Majority consensus and a minority controversy?  It seems that in each, the majority all agree and a minority disagree?

Comment: A "minority consensus" is a paradox and, I guess, it's not an intentional oxymoron!

Comment: Well then perhaps replacing minority/majority should occur, I don't want to get as simple as fewer/greater though - unless that's the best?

Comment: As Jim, I see a strong correlation between the two axis (X axis=consensus<>controversy, Y axis=majority/minority). Without a clarification on what is the effective difference between them, I don't think that we can help.

Comment: There's something **very** appealing about this graphic. In lieu of 'majority consensus': maybe **unanimity** (everyone in agreement). If you go with that change in that corner, then it should become easier to rethink 'minority consensus' and the label at bottom right.